# How to make widget not appear on some pages/posts using WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing widget, that displays additional data for post. On Edit/New Post page added metabox with fields to input this additional data. So the goal is to make this widget appear ONLY for posts where this data is set, and not appear where its not. Widget is in sidebar.

(I don't need advice to use "some other plugin" and need not to mess with theme templates).

Edit: I found some hook called "sidebar_widgets", and it passes $sidebar_widgets object in callback func.

Comment: Did you try anything? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: The problem is - i have no idea - i finished everything i need with this plugin, and only thing i dont know - is how to control it to appear only on some pages... i can control its content for sure - but i dont know how you can filter its actual appearence. WP docs is not helpful - i mean its dreadfull... Found some tips in others plugins, something with 'sidebar-widgets' hook

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current post's meta field in widget's `widget` method. I.e.:

```
class MyAwesomeWidget extends WP_Widget {}

  // ...

  function widget ( $args, $instance ) {

    // display only on pages that have _show_my_awesome_widget meta field set to "1"
    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_show_my_awesome_widget', true ) != 1 )
      return;

    // do your widget stuff here
    // ...

  }

}
```

Comment: Omg, it worked... I feel so stupid, i'm sorry to bother you. I haven't tried just return; , i tried only print ''; and it was inserting empty widget. Thank you!!